# Negative speedup When parallelising Vector Vector dot product

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

I have a subroutine which calculates vector dot product of large vectors. I have parallelised it using open MP. The following is my code:

```
double scalarProd(double* vec1, double* vec2, int n){
double prod = 0.0;
int chunk = 10; 
int i;
//double* c = (double*) malloc(n*sizeof(double));

omp_set_num_threads(4);

#pragma omp parallel
{
    double pprod = 0.0;
    #pragma omp for
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        pprod += vec1[i]*vec2[i];
    }

    #pragma omp critical
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        prod += pprod;
    }
}
```

return prod;
}

Can someone please tell me what is going wrong here? I am a newbie to multithreading

Edit:

Adding more information. Sorry, first timer here at SO.

The above mentioned subroutine is called from my function ConjugateGradient() multiple  times. I have now added the time calculation code in my ConjugateGradient function as below:

```
start_dotprod = omp_get_wtime();
rm_rm_old = scalarProd(rm,rm,MAT->ncols);
    run_dotprod = omp_get_wtime() - start_dotprod;
fprintf(timing,"Time taken by rm_rm dot product : %lf \n",run_dotprod);
```

Observed results : Time taken for the dot product
Sequential Version : 0.000007s
Parallel Version   : 0.002110

I am doing a simple compile using gcc -fopenmp command on Linux OS on my Intel I7 laptop.

I am currently using a matrix of size n = 5000.

I am getting huge speed down overall since the same dot product gets called multiple times till convergence is achieved( around 80k times).

Please suggest me any improvements. I feel I am doing something terribly wrong.

Thanks! :)

Comment: C and C++ are different languages; remove the tag of the one you are not using.

Comment: Are you by any chance using `clock()` to measure the execution time on Linux?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide more context with your question: How many threads, what hardware (CPU), how do you measure time, what vector sizes. Also please provide an [mcve].

Comment: What compiler? What compiler options? Did you compile with optimization (e.g. `-O3` with GCC/Clang/ICC or `/O2` with MSVC)? How did you time it? What is the size of `n`?.  85s is long long time so either you did not use optimization and/or `n` is very very large in which case the operations is memory bandwidth bound and the parallel version would not be much faster than the serial anyway.

Answer (score -2):

Prod is private for every thread, but its value is dependent on the previous iteration. Try:

prod[i]+=vec1[i]*vec2[i];

Comment: Nope, `prod` is a reduction variable.